# Printing records for custom module

Tags: python-2.7, report, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I am trying to print a report for my custom module, How can we add printing reports functionality to a custom module, any documentation will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have all the information in the [Odoo Documentation (Qweb Reports)](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/reports.html#report)